# date minus another date in xslt

Tags: xslt

Hope someone can help. I am trying to compare 2 dates inside an XML file and using a XSLT to do some calculation:

For example I have 2 dates in XML: 2011-05-23 and 2011-04-29. I want to do calculation inside XSLT like below:

('2011-05-23'-'2011-04-29')*30 = 24*30= 720

Can anyone shed any light?

Comment: Is XSLT 2.0 an option for you?

Comment: How do I know if XSLT 2.0 is available on my server?

Comment: Find out what XSLT engine you are using, and verify it's capabilities. The fastest/easiest way to check if you have XSLT 2.0 support in your current environment would be to try executing a 2.0 stylesheet, like the one I posted, that leverages 2.0 capabilities. A 1.0 processor will not successfully run it and will throw errors about non-supported XSLT/XPath 2.0 functions.

Answer (score 3):

**An XSLT 2.0 solution**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:value-of select="days-from-duration(
                                         xs:date('2011-05-23')
                                         - xs:date(xs:date('2011-04-29'))
                      )*30"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Yields: `720`

- `xs:date()` function evaluates the dates, which can be used to perform date operations
- subtracting the second date from the first yields the `xdt:dayTimeDuration` `P24D` (24 days)
- `days-from-duration()` extracts the days component from the `xdt:dayTimeDuration` (24)
- then you can use that number to perform normal arethmatic (e.g. `24*30=720`)

Comment: How do I knoe if XSLT2.0 can be used by me?

Answer (score 2):

It might be worth looking at the [EXSLT - date:difference](http://www.exslt.org/date/functions/difference/index.html) solution. I believe that should do what you want, and there's even a straight XSLT implementation available.

Be aware though that the returned value is in duration format as specified in the [XML Schema Part 2: Datatypes Second Edition](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#duration), so it's likely you will need to process the result to derive the unit you wish to use in calculation (for instance in your example above you're expecting a result detailing the number of days difference - so you would need to pull out the relevant unit you want to work with, the result from date:difference in that case would most likely be "P24D").

Answer (score 2):

Here's two templates I sometimes use for date calculations:

```
<xsl:template name="calcseconds">
  <xsl:param name="date" />
  <xsl:value-of select="(((substring($date,1,4) - 1970) * 365)+floor((substring($date,1,4) - 1970) div 4)+substring('000,031,059,090,120,151,181,212,243,273,304,334,365',substring($date,6,2)*4-3,3)+(substring($date,9,2)-1)+(1-floor(((substring($date,1,4) mod 4) + 2) div 3))*floor((substring($date,6,2)+17) div 20))*86400+(substring($date,12,2)*3600)+(substring($date,15,2)*60)+substring($date,18,2)" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="calcdays">
  <xsl:param name="date" />
  <xsl:value-of select="(((substring($date,1,4) - 1970) * 365)+floor((substring($date,1,4) - 1970) div 4)+substring('000,031,059,090,120,151,181,212,243,273,304,334,365',substring($date,6,2)*4-3,3)+(substring($date,9,2)-1)+(1-floor(((substring($date,1,4) mod 4) + 2) div 3))*floor((substring($date,6,2)+17) div 20))" />
</xsl:template>
```

They're a bit of a mouthful, but they'll calculate the number of seconds/days since midnight 1st January 1970 as an integer, which you can then do straight arithmetic on. They rely on the date format being `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`, but manipulation of the parameters of the substring calls should allow you to process dates in any format you need.